# Set the checkbox as checked by default in menu item page

Tags: menus

I'm modified `Walker_Nav_Menu_Edit` class and I added three radio input boxes within the menu items. The checkboxes are work perfectly but when add new menu item show all three checkboxes unchecked. I want when add new menu item the first checkbox is checked by default.

```
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemwithouticon" <?php checked($item->menuitemlayouts, 'itemwithouticon'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemwithicon" <?php checked($item->menuitemlayouts, 'itemwithicon'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemicon" <?php checked($item->menuitemlayouts, 'itemicon'); ?> />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `$item->menuitemlayouts` has value if not set checked for the first one...

```
<?php echo $item->menuitemlayouts ? checked($item->menuitemlayouts, 'itemwithouticon', true) : 'checked="checked"'; ?>
```

In the `checked()` I added the 3rd arg so it won't echo twice..

```
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemwithouticon" <?php echo $item->menuitemlayouts ? checked($item->menuitemlayouts, 'itemwithouticon', true) : 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemwithicon" <?php checked($item->menuitemlayouts, 'itemwithicon'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemicon" <?php checked($item->menuitemlayouts, 'itemicon'); ?> />
```

Or alternative just set a variable for this with default value if its not set.

```
<?php
$menuitemlayouts = $item->menuitemlayouts ? $item->menuitemlayouts : 'itemwithouticon';
?>
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemwithouticon" <?php checked($menuitemlayouts, 'itemwithouticon'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemwithicon" <?php checked($menuitemlayouts, 'itemwithicon'); ?> />
<input type="radio" name="menu-item-menuitemlayouts[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="itemicon" <?php checked($menuitemlayouts, 'itemicon'); ?> />
```